# Capturar eventos http de control de acceso en Hikvision

Tags: consultar

Quiero capturar los eventos cuando una persona pase la tarjeta de control de acceso por uno de mis dispositivos, he ido al panel de eventos y alarmas y he configurado un evento de control de acceso de paso correcto de tarjeta y acceso concedido mediante tarjeta, he configurado que accesos controlar, En la opción de añadir acción de conexión no hay ninguna opción para que envíe mediante http una solicitud a un servidor.
Me gustaría saber como puedo configurar el HikCentral Professional Web Client, para poder recibir los eventos http en mi servidor web.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Esto es un problema de programacion??? si es de configuracion, este sitio no trata esos problemas....